# What to do with the unused identity after deleting a row?

Tags: database

I have a user table that has 4 rows with id = 1, 2, 3, 4. I delete the row with id = 2 and insert another user and the user will get id = 5. What will happen to the id = 2? Will it be used again or do I rearrange the ids? Rearranging ids doesn't make sense if I have a large amount for every delete operation.

Comment: Is this specific to a particular RDMS? ID fields are usually auto incrementing, but depending on your engine, the specific functionality can vary a little.

Comment: What do you mean by rearranging?  Surely not some kind of renumbering??

Comment: I have the table in Postgresql, I guess it is a relational database. Sorry, I am not used to the DB terms. Yes, I understand that it will increase the number by itself. Rearranging here means like I removed the user with id = 2, so the next thing I do is to change id of user with id = 3 to id = 2, user with id = 4 to id = 3

Comment: Generally speaking it is a very bad idea to reassign ids, because they are a kind of name. It would be very confusing indeed if today `cat` stood for a four legged creature with fur, and tomorrow it only represented a star prior to supernova. Similarly the `2` in this table was associated with a specific definition. RDBMS systems are aware of this, and one approach (but no the only approach) is to assign the next highest number. Eventually you may have identified enough rows that there are no larger integers in the id. In this instance the RDBMS will either complain, or reuse deleted ids.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I had the same thought, assign enough rows for the ID. This clarified everything I need to know for my first app.

Comment: What happened? It was overlooked by the DB engine because looking for the smallest possible new ID would take linear time (or extra effort for tracking the minimum explicitly), while the *next* ID is already tracked and can be read in constant time.

Answer (score 6):

You don't do anything. The deleted IDs are gone forever.

No, that isn't a problem.

The primary purpose of the ID is simply to be unique. Deleting some IDs never to be seen again doesn't affect the uniqueness of others. Most DB engines provide an automatic ID assignment capability, you should use it.

Just make sure you allocate enough bits in your ID to provide enough room during your application's life, that's all you have to do. Do not try to roll an id recycling system.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Knowing this ease my mind a lot.